# Find User Role ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-roles

Trying to find out where roles are assigned to a particular user in an ASP.Net core app. I'm new to .net core so bare with me. I can debug and see the username and password but cannot figure out where the roles are set for this particular user? If there's something else I need to add here please advise.

I use the login provide and get ***"No roles assigned."*** below for the user. I have in the Login.cshtml.cs page:

```
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");

                    var user = _signInManager.UserManager.Users.Where(a => a.Email == Input.Email).FirstOrDefault();

                    if (user == null || !user.IsActive)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                        return Page();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

                        if (!roles.Any())
                        {
                            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "No roles assigned.");
                            return Page();
                        }

                        if ((returnUrl ?? "").Length < 1)
                        {
                            returnUrl = await GetRoleHomepage(user);
                        }
                    }

                    return RedirectToPage(returnUrl);
                }
```

Honestly, I'm used to website's, the old school pages because I'm coming from local government which is far behind private. Now I'm private and now stressed. Looking at the AccountController.cs I see:

```
    [Route("[controller]/[action]")]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private readonly SignInManager<AspNetUsers> _signInManager;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public AccountController(SignInManager<AspNetUsers> signInManager, ILogger<AccountController> logger)
        {
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
        {
            await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
            _logger.LogInformation("User logged out.");
            return RedirectToPage("/Index");
        }
    }
```

Thanks for the input: The only part I see with IdentityRole is in a class with this but it's empty:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace Portal.HPAG.Data
{
    public partial class AspNetRoles : IdentityRole
    {
    }
}
```

And then I found a AspNetRoles class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Portal.HPAG.Data
{
    public partial class AspNetRoles
    {
        public AspNetRoles()
        {
            AspNetUserRoles = new HashSet<AspNetUserRoles>();
            PartStatusTypeRoles = new HashSet<PartStatusTypeRoles>();
            RoleLevels = new HashSet<RoleLevels>();
            Stage = new HashSet<Stage>();
        }

        public string Id { get; set; }
        public bool IsManager { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<AspNetUserRoles> AspNetUserRoles { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PartStatusTypeRoles> PartStatusTypeRoles { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<RoleLevels> RoleLevels { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Stage> Stage { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Still digging through.

Comment: Search your code for a call to __userManager.AddToRoleAsync_

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `AddToRoleAsync(TUser user, string role)` and `IsInRoleAsync`, you should be able to iterating through roles in an `IEnumerable<IdentityRole>` variable.

You should be able to set a new variable for `_roleManager` using:

```
serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can learn how to use [UserManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1?view=aspnetcore-6.0) and [RoleManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.rolemanager-1?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to manager your user and role. There are many methods encapsulated in Them. You can use `UserManager` and `RoleManager` via dependency injection like `signInManager`.

**I list a few very common methods below：**

> Add role in user: `userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, role.Name);`
>
> Add the specified user to the named roles:
> `userManager.AddToRolesAsync(user, IEnumerable<role.Name>)`
>
> Returns a list of users from the user store who are members of the
> specified roleName: `userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync(role.Name)`
>
> Returns a flag indicating whether the specified user is a member of
> the given named role: `userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, role.Name)`

There are other methods that I haven't listed, you can check them out through the hyperlinks I provided.